# Why is checking void 0 so much faster than checking undefined?

Tags: javascript, performance

I noticed something interesting after using gulp-uglify on my concatenated javascript. I was passing in `undefined` to a global IIFE wrapper and I saw that it was changing it to `void 0`. What the heck is void 0? I ran it in the console and it returned undefined. Interesting! This got me curious, so I started running tests on void 0. In my console tests (simple loops and timestamps), I have observed as much as a 180x speed increase, depending on browser, checking `void 0` instead of `undefined`. Does anyone know why checking void 0 is so much faster?

```
(function(start, x, z){
    for (var i=0; i<z; i++){
      if (x === undefined){}
    }
    console.info('t1 ', Date.now() - start);
    start = Date.now();
    for (var i=0; i<z; i++){
      if (x === void 0){}
    }
    console.info('t1 ', Date.now() - start);
})(Date.now(), '', 1e6)
```

Comment: You're seeing runtime optimization. Your loops don't do anything, so it's possible for the runtime to simply not execute the loops at all. The symbol `undefined` is just a pre-defined variable, and it may or may not actually be equal to `void 0`; that loop therefore may not be optimized away.

Comment: @Pointy I thought `undefined` was a primitive and `void(0)`/`void 0` was just an expression to obtain `undefined`?

Comment: No, void 0 is a primitive, undefined is a global variable.

Comment: No, `undefined` is not a built-in primitive. It's weird but that's the way it works. Try `undefined = 17;` in your developer console.

Comment: "The `void` operator is often used merely to obtain the `undefined` primitive value" ah, it's not saying that it *is* a primitive value, but `void` is being used to obtain it's prim val. That makes more sense now

Comment: The *value* `undefined` is a primitive, but it's accessed via a global variable when using the identifier.

Comment: Overall, take micro-benchmarks with a huge grain of salt. They're very hard to get right. A single test shouldn't be too convincing. And I would think that most implementations could statically determine that the global `undefined` has not been shadowed, and therefore optimize the scope chain traversal.

Comment: @user2612030: `void 0` is an expression (using the `void` operator) that returns the primitive `undefined`, just like SterlingArcher wrote.

Comment: @Pointy, you're wrong: point first, `void` keyword runs the expression after itself, so the for does something: runs 0 for each iteration! Point second, I tried the same code but creating and removing element in the DOM to do something more for each iteration. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuyhcjwn/10/).

Comment: @DavideCannizzo what?

Comment: @DavideCannizzo: You're missing his point. Optimizing compilers rewrite code to be more efficient and can sometimes entirely remove code. So with `x === void 0`, if they can statically determine the value of `x` as `""`, then they can remove the entire operation because they know that the `0` in `void 0` has no side effect and that the comparison will always be `false`. Therefore they can also drop the entire loop.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I just realized the difference between `void 0` and `undefined`. `undefined` is a value on global scope and `void` is an operator. What's happening in this test is that undefined was being checked globally whereas `void 0`, since it is an expression using the operator `void`, does not require scope traversal in order to check its value. If you pass in `undefined` to the IIFE wrapper, the test results will be the same. The performance discrepancy shown in the original test actually only measured the time-cost of scope traversal 1e6 times.

Further code proof that this is the case. The for loops below have the same execution time:

```
(function(start, x, z, undefined, c, Math){
    for (var i=0; i<z; i++){
    if (x !== undefined){
        c = Math.random();
    }
    }
    console.info('t1 ', Date.now() - start);
    start = Date.now();
    c = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<z; i++){
        if (x !== void 0){
            c = Math.random();
        }
    }
    console.info('t1 ', Date.now() - start);
})(Date.now(), '', 1e6, undefined, 0, Math)
```

[rock star](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8897421/rock-star) does make a good point that the results are subject to how your code is written, such as whether the conditionally assigned values in memory are accessed or not. Based on my tests, it will vary a lot if you take the values and pass it as an argument to a function. At that point the browser may decide to do fewer optimizations. Nevertheless, in every test I've run `void 0` is still faster than or equivalent to `undefined`, uses less kb, and it removes concerns about traversing scope.

Comment: *"The performance discrepancy shown in the original test actually only measured the time-cost of scope traversal 1e6 times."* What about the loop itself? How are optimizations performed? How many passes does it take, and in what order? Maybe with `void 0`, their optimizations let them eliminate the `if ` statement early enough to eliminate the entire loop, but with `undefined`, the `if` gets eliminated, but on a later pass, so the loop itself remains. Or maybe with `undefined` the `if` stays, but the scope traversal gets eliminated, so the loop and the `===` comparison remain.

Comment: It's not optimizing the loop in any sense. You can stick whatever you want inside of the `if` block or evaluate `void 0` and `undefined` however you want. The results are the same. Furthermore, injecting undefined into the IIFE makes the results exactly the same, proving that the `if` loop is not being secretly optimized by the browser.

Comment: Why would putting something in the `if` block change anything? The `if` is always `false`, so the code inside will never run. And to declare that the loop isn't optimized in any sense is quite silly. You have no idea what optimizations are taking place and under what conditions they may occur. Unless you're going to tell me that you've studied the source code of the implementations you're testing?

Comment: *"proving that the if loop is not being secretly optimized by the browser"* No, you didn't read my comment very carefully about the possibility of multiple optimization passes, and when they may take place in relation to each other. Perhaps any optimizations related to globals take place at the very end so that they can have some assurances that they're not altered or shadowed. You're assuming far too much in the face of the immense complexity of modern optimizing compilers.

Comment: Read my comment again. I said evaluate void 0 and undefined however you want.

Comment: Why would a different evaluation of `undefined` make a difference? If (for example) they don't optimize globals until a very late pass, it could be that the scope traversal does get eliminated but the loop itself doesn't. You seem to have decided that you know low level characteristics of implementations and can't imagine it being any other way. Also, I have a strong hunch that you're testing in the developer console. Am I right?

Comment: Quoting myself from above *"Overall, take micro-benchmarks with a huge grain of salt. They're very hard to get right."*. What makes you think that the local `c` isn't known at compile time to be unused, and therefore the `Math.random()` operation and assignment optimized away? These are some of the most simple and obvious optimizations for anyone remotely familiar with optimizing compilers.

Comment: Here's an example using Google's Closure Compiler, which is an optimizing *transpiler*. Your last code example is reduced to this: `for(var a=Date.now(),b=0;1E6>b;b++);console.info("t1 ",Date.now()-a);a=Date.now();for(b=0;1E6>b;b++);console.info("t1 ",Date.now()-a);` Notice that *this* optimizer keeps *both* loops, but they're empty, *perhaps* because it first optimized away the IIFE, causing the vars to be globals, which are kept. I think there's a setting to keep the IIFE, which would likely eliminate the loops too.

Comment: ...so don't draw such hard and fast conclusions about performance, because you, and most of the rest of us, just don't know. BTW, you haven't answered if you're testing in the console. If so, that's another big mistake.

Comment: Well, since you're not deleting this incorrect answer, I'll add a better perf test to show that there ends up being virtually no difference, so others are not misled. https://jsfiddle.net/nv0pjch8/ It forces the loop to fill an array with `Math.random()` values and then prints a value from the loop at a random index. That way, the compiler can not know which one will be chosen, so it can't eliminate any of them.

Comment: ...funny thing is that in Firefox they're equal, but in Chrome, the global is much faster than the local. Shows different optimizations at play.